# SDWebImageView using with UIImageView inside a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, facebook, uitableview, swift, uiimageview

I'm using the Facebook Graph API to fetch some posts of some users and want to display them inside my app. To keep it simple, here's how I get the posts from the Graph API:

```
FBRequestConnection.startWithGraphPath("/me/home", parameters: ["limit" : 20, "fields" : "id,from,to,message,type,link,story,picture,object_id", "until" : 1424364646], HTTPMethod: "GET", completionHandler: {(FBRequestConnection connection, AnyObject result, NSError error) -> () in
        if let json = result as? NSMutableDictionary {
            self.newsFeedPostsJSON = json
            self.dataArray = self.newsFeedPostsJSON.objectForKey("data") as [FBGraphObject]!
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() in
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
       }
})
```

That works pretty good (don't mind the parameters I've set here). Now, I have my *self.dataArray* which stores all the posts that are returned by this request.

In my *tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath* I prepare my cell, which is different for every type of post. I have the types *video, photo, link* and a normal status.

So if a user posts a link (or gets tagged in a life event etc.), my cell will look like this:
[image]

Now, there is that great framework called *SDWebImage*  (https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage), which is an extension for UIImageView to download images asynchronously.

Now, here is that function:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell : StatusTableViewCell!

    var graphObject = self.dataArray[indexPath.row] as FBGraphObject

    if let type = graphObject.objectForKey("type") as? String {
        switch(type) {
            case "video":
                cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(self.NewsFeedVideoStatusCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? NewsFeedVideoStatusTableViewCell
                cell.setupProgressView()
                if let picture = graphObject.objectForKey("picture") as String? {
                    var pictureURL = NSURL(string: picture)
                    (cell as NewsFeedVideoStatusTableViewCell).videoThumbImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(pictureURL, completed: {(image: UIImage!, error : NSError!, cacheType : SDImageCacheType!, url) -> Void in
                        (cell as NewsFeedVideoStatusTableViewCell).progressView.stopSpinProgressBackgroundLayer()
                        (cell as NewsFeedVideoStatusTableViewCell).progressView.removeFromSuperview()
                    })
                }
            case "link":
                cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(self.NewsFeedLinkStatusCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? NewsFeedLinkStatusTableViewCell
                cell.setupProgressView()
            case "photo":
                cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(self.NewsFeedPhotoStatusCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? NewsFeedPhotoStatusTableViewCell
                cell.setupProgressView()
                if let objectID = graphObject.objectForKey("object_id") as String! {
                    FBRequestConnection.startWithGraphPath("/\(objectID)", parameters: ["fields" : "images"], HTTPMethod: "GET", completionHandler: {(FBRequestConnection connection, AnyObject result, NSError error) -> () in
                        if let imagesArray = (result as NSDictionary).objectForKey("images") as NSArray? {
                            (cell as NewsFeedPhotoStatusTableViewCell).photoImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(self.getImageURLwithWidthAndHeightBetween(imagesArray, lower: 200, upper: 500), completed: {(image: UIImage!, error: NSError!, cacheType: SDImageCacheType!, url) -> Void in
                                (cell as NewsFeedPhotoStatusTableViewCell).progressView.stopSpinProgressBackgroundLayer()
                                (cell as NewsFeedPhotoStatusTableViewCell).progressView.removeFromSuperview()
                            })
                        }
                    })
                }
            default:
                cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(self.NewsFeedNormalStatusCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? NewsFeedNormalStatusTableViewCell
        }
    }
```

So, my tableview cell for a video looks nearly the same as it looks for a link. A video has a small thumbnail, its URL is provided in the JSON object with the key '*picture*'.

When it comes to that line

```
(cell as NewsFeedVideoStatusTableViewCell).videoThumbImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(pictureURL, completed: {(image: UIImage!, error : NSError!, cacheType : SDImageCacheType!, url) -> Void in
```

my App crashed. Xcode gives me the error "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" and I don't know how to solve that. I think it has to do with the completion handler and the reference to my table view cell.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Check to see if `videoThumbImageView` is `nil` or not. If the `IBOutlet` wasn't hooked up properly in the cell prototype, it could be `nil`, causing problems.

Comment: It is hooked up properly, checked that already. And I also don't get the "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping" or something like that. EXC_BAD_ACCESS looks like the access to the cell's image view is not allowed at that point. But I don't know how to make that working?

Comment: You don't always see the graceful "unexpected found nil". Glad you solved your problem nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out. Xcode showed me the error in the wrong line. My code was working properly. The problem is: I can't access the cells image view in the completion handler (that are these two lines:

```
(cell as NewsFeedVideoStatusTableViewCell).progressView.stopSpinProgressBackgroundLayer()
(cell as NewsFeedVideoStatusTableViewCell).progressView.removeFromSuperview()
```

It doesn't even work if I put these two lines on the main thread, always crashing. Will have to find a workaround to hide my progress view when the image download finished.

Comment: Excellent. When you log `(cell as NewsFeedVideoStatusTableViewCell).progressView` are you getting what you expect?

Comment: Nope. App crashes before it writes something to the console.